# Collecting initial data in one big view or in few steps?

Tags: gui-design, user-behavior, android, data-entry

On the user first login, I have to collect some data from the user to enable app to do it's stuff.

I would like not to frighten user and discourage him/her from using the app..

1. Should I put data into one bigger scroll view and tell user this is all data you would need to enter (i.e. no endless steps) 
   Or
2. Should I collect data in few steps (cca 3 steps) with smaller amount of data on each screen?

What is more user friendly?

Comment: Does the user need to enter the data or simply accept?

Comment: Most of it he would need to enter.

Comment: And most of the data is really important and has to be valid, because the app is part of the tax reporting system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is something else. It is not about how to show (single step or multiple steps).

> It depends on what information you are asking.

There are two origins of informations. One is stored in user's mind and other is out of their mind. Obviously, they feel easy and quick to express right from their mind.

Let me create an example. You are asked to fill your passport no.(8 digit) and mobile no. (10 digit). Which is less headache? huh?

You got it right?

Now let's focus on its presentation aspect. I don't see much problem to ask informations like mobile no. in multiple steps. Sure it'll be more **user friendly** than one long scroll. Now you might be thinking how to ask information that is NOT stored in user's mind like tax ID.

No user feel better at 3rd step (after login) **asking tax ID**. They wish they could have been informed before. If the tax document was not nearby, they wouldn't have started filling the form.

Make sense right?

[image]

Now it is upto you to decide what is best for your app.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I collect data in few steps

Yes you should be collecting the data in steps. that makes users life a bit easier since he doesn't have to scroll through your app. (**as the data is important for you not the user!**).

Also consider showing him his progress through this process. may be like

1. He is in step 2 of 3
2. He is completed 30% of total

which ever is suitable in your case, in that way user knows that he is not lost somewhere in no mans land in your app. hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how many inputs required for this process. If all the inputs fit into one screen (doesn't need to scroll) it's better to use only one step.

If they don't, you can divide the form-filling process by their data category to be several steps/sections. A very long form discourage user to fill all the input, meanwhile form with steps help users to be more focused on what informations does the app need for a time. It also give an impression that the form is shorter than it actually is.

Don't forget the progress bar with button to navigate between forms sections. Technically, I will make all the form as a single webpage to eliminate loading time and to send all the data at once.

[You may want to check this out.](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/01/progress-trackers-in-web-design-examples-and-best-design-practices/)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

[Material design - Steppers](https://material.io/guidelines/components/steppers.html#):

> Steppers display progress through a sequence by breaking it up into multiple logical and numbered steps.
>
> Avoid using steppers to break up sections in a short form, or multiple times on one page.

In order to make a decision consider:

- **Is the form long enough?**
- **Are there logical steps?**

> I would like not to frighten user and discourage him/her from using the app.

I don't think it makes much difference when I am being asked for certain information. If I see that an app asks me for information I don't want to give, I will quit at any point. For this concern, the sooner I know which information is required the better not to waste time.

Comment: I think @jivan has more to say about logical step.

Comment: @Paliza He has a very good point on the "physical" aspect of being asked for related information in the same step.